# Can I apply Monotone Convergence to $\int_{0}^\infty e^{-x} dx = \lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{0}^{n} (1 - x/n)^n dx = 1$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Can I apply Monotone Convergence to $\int_{0}^\infty e^{-x} dx = \lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{0}^{n} (1 - x/n)^n dx = 1?$

So the sequence $f_n= (1 - x/n)^n $ is nonnegative and increasing and converges point wise to $e^{-x}$. Everything seems to be setting up for the theorem.

But I have two questions

1. Since the limit of integration $\int_{0}^n$, is it allowed to apply the theorem when the index are also increasing? The theorem is stated without any set in the integral
2. Suppose (1) is resolved and the theorem can be applied. Why am I allowed to evaluate $\int_{0}^\infty e^{-x} dx$ as a **Riemann** integral? How do I know its Lesbegue $(L)\int_{0}^\infty e^{-x} dx$ coincides with its $R\int_{0}^\infty e^{-x} dx$? Simply because the limits in the Monotone Convergence theorem exists? And therefore the Lesbegue integral exists and coincides with Rieman Integral?

Comment: I won't write an answer because I don't want to search the literature for the second question. I presume you can adapt the argument here - https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/218350/improper-riemann-integral-and-lebesgue-integral For the first, you just need to consider $(1-x/n)^n \mathbb 1_{x\in[0,n]}\ge 0$ which does increase to $e^{-x}\ge 0$

Comment: I got it from Narother, but I just opened Royden and apparently we can insert any measurable set $E$. So I guess any measurable set works. So is there no issue of taking an index that increases in the limits of integration? Is there even a need to introduce characteristic function here?

Comment: Your question is odd to me because I define the Lebesgue integral $\int_A f(x) d\mu(x)$ by using the characteristic function
$$ \int_A f(x) d\mu(x) := \int_X f(x) \mathbb 1_A (x) d\mu (x) $$
so its not that I introduced anything, I just applied the definition.

I also don't know what you're quoting from Narother and Royden. PS the title is different from question body ($\int_0^{\color{red} n} e^{-x} dx$)

Comment: I mean that's just one representation right? usually it is introduced as the supremum of integrals of simple functions.

Comment: No, I believe the integral over the whole measure space is usually introduced(:= defined) as that quantity. Though it has been a while since I checked my foundational definitions

Comment: I was quoting the Monotone Convergence theorem stated in their books. Yes the title as typos, I fixed one but I missed that one. I fix now.

Comment: I don't understand what you are saying. There is no way that any correct book will allow the integration domain to change in their statement of monotone convergence theorem. To apply this theorem to your changing domain, apply the definition of the integral which uses the indicator. What part of this do you not understand?

Answer (score 0):

Using Lebesgue integral with respect to a measure $\mu$ you can write
$$\int_{(0,\infty)}e^{-x}d\mu=\int \lim_{n \to \infty} 1_{[1/n,n]}(x)(1 - x/n)^n d\mu $$

Since $1_{[1/n,n]}(x)(1- x/n)^n\geq 0$ and it's increasing with respect to $n$ (check the derivatives) you can apply Beppo-Levi theorem yielding

$$\int_{(0,\infty)}e^{-x}d\mu= \int \lim_{n \to \infty} 1_{[1/n,n]}(x)(1 - x/n)^n d\mu =\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\int 1_{[1/n,n]}(x)(1 - x/n)^n d\mu$$

Since the function $(1 - x/n)^n$ is continuous  and bounded in $[1/n,n]$ we know that it's Riemann itegrable in that interval. We know that if the Riemann integral exists then the Lebesgue integral exists and **they coincide**.

Hence we can write the latter as
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} (\mathfrak R)\int_{1/n}^n (1 - x/n)^ndx$$

If this limit exists then the improper Riemann integral must coincide with the Lebesgue integral, namely$(\mathfrak R)\int_0^{\infty}e^{-x}dx=\int_{(0,\infty)} e^{-x}d\mu$.

[I am using Theorems 9.6, 11.8 and corollary 11.9 from "Measures, Integrals and Martingales" by Robert Schilling. ]